# La funcion multicell de la libreria fpdf me rellena la celda aunque le ponga FALSE

Tags: fpdf

La cambio por un CELL y ahí sí funcione el FALSE para que no la rellene pero me interesa MULTICELL porque es la descripcion de un articulo de varias lineas dentro de la celda.

Comment: podrías agregar tu código ?